# My isp gave me 1 modem and 1 router which i have in my house but later they gave 2 other connections to different users from my modem

Tags: internet, modem, isp

My isp gave me 1 modem and 1 router which i have in my house but later they gave 2 other connections to different users from my modem. Are they cheating other users or they can just use my modem for different users?

Comment: Sounds very irregular (where I live), I would check your contract. I certainly would not want people I don't know using my internet connection, could mean they have easy access to your devices too.

Comment: Is the modem inside your house, or is it an apartment?

Comment: You're going to have to describe what you mean by "gave 2 other connections". As in they gave out your WiFi password? Or there is a guest WiFi connection? We cannot see what you can see so you need to be clear about what is happening.